# iPhone - Is it possible to communicate with the iAd server directly?

Tags: iphone, ios, iad

I dont this this is possible but the client seams to think it is..

They want their server to communicate with the iAd server then send some information to the App to tell it what advert to load.

My understanding is that only the private `ADBannerView` class can communicate with the iAd server, is this correct or is there potential to integrate with it via a server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a client request this as well, I think they misunderstand the role of iAds.

In my scenario it turned out that they wanted to serve their own ads (that they'd sourced, not necessarily for their product), so you might want to consider using a scenario where you have some file on their server with information like "imageurl" "image2xurl" "linkurl" and set up your app to look there, and if some value in the file is yes (some on/off Bool), then build a UIButton with those specs, with a method that will follow the link. It won't have the iAd frame (unless your client overlays that onto the images, but I'd suggest against that for a number of reasons)

Comment: Yes, I am thinking of suggesting something like that.

Answer (score 1):

Um, not that I know of. You can specify the ad types you want to exclude, i.e. a Coke app can say no Pepsi ads. I believe that is in iTunes Connect and is set on a app basis, nothing to do with direct communication with the iAd server.

Answer (score 0):

It's worse than that. iAds are designed to be difficult to obscure by your app — the ad banners seem to be displayed in another window (the position doesn't animate and they don't appear with `-[CALayer renderInContext:]`) and the full-screen ads are displayed in another process (you can interact with them even if you pause the app in the debugger). It's probably the one called AdSheet in Instruments' Activity Monitor.

I suspect AdSheet does the communication with the iAd server too.