# Can i load ads from my server when using AdMob for Iphone?

Tags: iphone, admob, ads

I am newbie to Admob. After some RnD, I know how to integrate Admob to an iphone app. But i wanted to  know is there a way that i can load ads from my server? If it is possible, can someone suggest some good tutorial/reference?

Thankyou for the anticipated response,

Regards,
Ainee

Answer (score 1):

That process is called [AbMob House Ads](http://helpcenter.admob.com/content/admob-house-ads). It allows you cross promote your own product.

Answer (score 0):

Or, outside of AdMob, you can do something like the solution here: [iPhone - Is it possible to communicate with the iAd server directly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5265068/iphone-is-it-possible-to-communicate-with-the-iad-server-directly/5265343#5265343)

Where you setup a file on your server with specifics about the ad (image, link destination, positioning [if applicable]), then pull in that information and programmatically build a UIButton with it, to make your own ad.